# How to initialize array of a complex object?

Tags: c++

I have:

```
class SomeObject {
public:
    SomeObject() { ... }
    // Other fields and methods
};

class anOtherObject {
private:
    SomeObject array[SOME_FIXED_SIZE];
public:
    anOtherObject() : ... { ... }

};
```

My question is - what does array contain when and after the constructor is called? should I initialize it by myself with a for loop or does the compiler call the default constructor for each array[i] , `0<=i<SOME_FIXED_SIZE` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The array is *default-initialized*, which means its elements are *default initialized* one by one. Since your array holds user defined types, this means their default constructor will be called. If your array held built-in types or PODs, you would have to be explicit and *value-initialize* it, since default initialization would mean no initialization is performed on the elements:

```
anOtherObject() : array() {}
//                ^^^^^^^ value-initialize array
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give an example for when I have to initialize the array by myself?

Comment: @Shmoopy Sure, but do you mean, using the value initialization as I do in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

when you create an object of type anOtherObject:
 anOtherObject  a;
since object a has a private array of type SomeObject, the default constructor of the SomeObject class shall be called for each element of the array. 
Before  the constructor is called the array should contain "garbage" since it's statically allocated on the stack. 
After the constructor is called the memory should contain whatever you set in the default constructor; e.g initializing everything to 0